# Post a string contains html tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want post a string to html file using ajax.

```
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
  if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
   alert ("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP");
   return;
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=getOutput;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In the url I sent the parameters what i want in the another file. It also contains a string with html tags like this

```
<table id='detReportTable' style='color:#333333;font-family:sans-serif;width:97%;margin-left:10px;'><tbody><tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align:center;'><div style='font-size: 19px;font-weight: bold;' id='score_cont'></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I sent this string as parameter but it does not get this parameter other parameters without having html tags will send eg: `foo=sample`. It shows me a error. Can i send this html string or my way is wrong please suggest any idea.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding (see the answer provided by Anentropic).

Comment: @JimH. If i use like that then this gets all & as a seperator for variable and it shows a lot of variable like lt and gt and thats value as null. So for sending value to another form its not worked

Comment: When you send data via GET method, there are only a limited set of characters that you can use (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter) - anything else **has** to be encoded in some way, or it will be an invalid call - if you need to send those characters the receiving end must treat the enconded values correctly and reconvert them to the original characters as needed.

Answer (score 0):

why not just pass all that info normally? Why do you need to include the html tags??

Your codes breaking because of the equals(=). You could replace all equals with ~, then the full parameter will get passed, and on the other page u can fix it by replacing ~ back to =

example:

> var parameters = " < table id='........ >";
>
> while( parameters.indexOf('=')>=0 ){
>
> parameters = parameters.replace('=','~');
>
> }

you'll also need to replace #