# Shortest possible encoded string with a decode possibility (shorten URL) using only PHP

Tags: php, encoding, decoding

I'm looking for a method that encodes a string to the **shortest** possible length and lets it be **decodable** (pure PHP, no SQL). I have working script, but I'm unsatisfied with the length of the encoded string.

*Scenario*

Link to an image (it depends on the file resolution I want to show to the user):

- ***[www.mysite.com/share/index.php?img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500](http://www.mysite.com/share/index.php?img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500)***

Encoded link (so the user can't guess how to get the larger image):

- ***[www.mysite.com/share/encodedQUERYstring](http://www.mysite.com/share/encodedQUERYstring)***

So, basically I'd like to encode only the search query part of the URL:

- ***img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500***

The method I use right now will encode the above query string to:

- ***y8xNt9VPySwC44xM3aLUYt3M3HS9rIJ0tXJbcwMDtQxbUwMDAA***

The method I use is:

```
 $raw_query_string = 'img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500';

 $encoded_query_string = base64_encode(gzdeflate($raw_query_string));
 $decoded_query_string = gzinflate(base64_decode($encoded_query_string));
```

How do I shorten the encoded result and still have the possibility to decode it using **only** PHP?

Comment: I will bite: **why** do you want to do this?

Comment: looks like home-made "security by obscurity" thing. Do not go that way. It's pointless and it's also a dead end.

Comment: **PeeHaa**, The whole idea (in this particular example) is to prevent anyone to gets a hi-res image (not to prevent it completely but just to minimize possibility). I know it could be done better, but I just want this simple "plug and play". I'm pretty sure that a regular user would not try to decode it. On the other side, I'm just curious to how short result I could encode an string (even for other purposes).

Comment: **why** are you trying to prevent the user from getting a hi-res image?

Comment: **th3falc0n**, because I'm a photographer. If an user would like to have hi-res (7360x4912px) image, he could buy it.

Comment: If you want your users to purchase high-res images, then don't display them in web pages.... display a lower resolution image and/or watermark the images that you display

Comment: **Mark Baker**, this is not a solution if you want your web page looks good. These days I could simply show 800px images, but after 2 years they will be unwatchable because screen resolutions getting higher and higher. Then, instead of reediting all images and reuploading them again, I could simply raise image resolution inside my image parser.

Comment: The instance you display an image on your website, it's downloaded to the a user's PC when they display that page.... if you're displaying the high-res image, then they now have that image on their PC.... and it doesn't matter how much you obfusticate the link

Comment: **Mark Baker**, I'm fully aware of that. Therefore the point is that the instance he get is just a preview item: `w=700&h=500` , not the full size image. If I decide some day that the preview images are too small (for any reason), I could simply raise the size to f.ex: `w=1200&h=800` which still is not even a half of the full resolution. Apart from the above, having this, I'm also not forced to keep few different sized copies of a single image for any other purposes.

Comment: i've done something like this. what i did was keep a  table on my db with unique ids of the shortened url segment and the long version.

Comment: I know you said no database, but can you **cheat** and write the hash and url it relates to to a file? or the users session? The problem with creating shorter hashes is that unless you can maintain state you can't verify that hashes are unique to an image so you could end up with hash collisions.

Comment: Is it just me, or is your "shorten URL" longer than the original parameters? Too short strings are where gzip & such algorithms fail at compressing (words declaration gets longer than their uses).

Comment: You can get shorter urls if you limit your input alphabet. If your paths are only consisting of the 26 lower case a-z letters with . - and /, and your resolution integers don't go more than 16k, would that be an acceptable compromise?  From my sums you can half the size of the url you are getting now, and it will actually end up shorter than the query string.

Comment: how about just str_replace and use pipes to separate params?
`mysite.com/share/?/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg|700|500`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suspect that you will need to think more about your method of hashing if you don't want it to be decodable by the user.  The issue with [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is that a Base64 string *looks* like a base64 string.  There's a good chance that someone that's savvy enough to be looking at your page source will probably recognise it too.

Part one:

> a method that encodes an string to shortest possible length

If you're flexible on your URL vocabulary/characters, this will be a good starting place.  Since [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) makes a lot of its gains using back references, there is little point as the string is so short.

Consider your example - you've only saved 2 bytes in the compression, which are lost again in Base64 padding:

Non-gzipped: `string(52) "aW1nPS9kaXIvZGlyL2hpLXJlcy1pbWcuanBnJnc9NzAwJmg9NTAw"`

Gzipped: `string(52) "y8xNt9VPySwC44xM3aLUYt3M3HS9rIJ0tXJbcwMDtQxbUwMDAA=="`

If you reduce your vocabulary size, this will naturally allow you better compression.  Let's say we remove some redundant information.

Take a look at the functions:

```
function compress($input, $ascii_offset = 38){
    $input = strtoupper($input);
    $output = '';
    //We can try for a 4:3 (8:6) compression (roughly), 24 bits for 4 characters
    foreach(str_split($input, 4) as $chunk) {
        $chunk = str_pad($chunk, 4, '=');

        $int_24 = 0;
        for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
            //Shift the output to the left 6 bits
            $int_24 <<= 6;

            //Add the next 6 bits
            //Discard the leading ASCII chars, i.e make
            $int_24 |= (ord($chunk[$i]) - $ascii_offset) & 0b111111;
        }

        //Here we take the 4 sets of 6 apart in 3 sets of 8
        for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
            $output = pack('C', $int_24) . $output;
            $int_24 >>= 8;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

And

```
function decompress($input, $ascii_offset = 38) {

    $output = '';
    foreach(str_split($input, 3) as $chunk) {

        //Reassemble the 24 bit ints from 3 bytes
        $int_24 = 0;
        foreach(unpack('C*', $chunk) as $char) {
            $int_24 <<= 8;
            $int_24 |= $char & 0b11111111;
        }

        //Expand the 24 bits to 4 sets of 6, and take their character values
        for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $output = chr($ascii_offset + ($int_24 & 0b111111)) . $output;
            $int_24 >>= 6;
        }
    }

    //Make lowercase again and trim off the padding.
    return strtolower(rtrim($output, '='));
}
```

It is basically a removal of redundant information, followed by the compression of 4 bytes into 3.  This is achieved by effectively having a 6-bit subset of the ASCII table.  This window is moved so that the offset starts at useful characters and includes all the characters you're currently using.

With the offset I've used, you can use anything from ASCII 38 to 102.  This gives you a resulting string of **30 bytes**, that's a 9-byte (24%) compression!  Unfortunately, you'll need to make it URL-safe (probably with base64), which brings it back up to 40 bytes.

I think at this point, you're pretty safe to assume that you've reached the "security through obscurity" level required to stop 99.9% of people.  Let's continue though, to the second part of your question

> so the user can't guess how to get the larger image

It's arguable that this is already solved with the above, but you need to pass this through a secret on the server, preferably with [PHP's OpenSSL interface](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php).  The following code shows the complete usage flow of functions above and the encryption:

```
$method = 'AES-256-CBC';
$secret = base64_decode('tvFD4Vl6Pu2CmqdKYOhIkEQ8ZO4XA4D8CLowBpLSCvA=');
$iv = base64_decode('AVoIW0Zs2YY2zFm5fazLfg==');

$input = 'img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500';
var_dump($input);

$compressed = compress($input);
var_dump($compressed);

$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($compressed, $method, $secret, false, $iv);
var_dump($encrypted);

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $secret, false, $iv);
var_dump($decrypted);

$decompressed = decompress($compressed);
var_dump($decompressed);
```

The output of this script is the following:

```
string(39) "img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500"
string(30) "<��(��tJ��@�xH��G&(�%��%��xW"
string(44) "xozYGselci9i70cTdmpvWkrYvGN9AmA7djc5eOcFoAM="
string(30) "<��(��tJ��@�xH��G&(�%��%��xW"
string(39) "img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500"
```

You'll see the whole cycle: compression → encryption → Base64 encode/decode → decryption → decompression.  The output of this would be as close as possible as you could really get, at near the shortest length you could get.

Everything aside, I feel obliged to conclude this with the fact that it is theoretical only, and this was a nice challenge to think about.  There are definitely better ways to achieve your desired result - I'll be the first to admit that my solution is a little bit absurd!

Comment: Thank you for putting some light on the question. It makes me understand the whole thing much much better

Answer (score 5):

## Theory

In theory we need a short input character set and a large output character set.
I will demonstrate it by the following example. We have the number 2468 as integer with 10 characters (0-9) as character set. We can convert it to the same number with base 2 (binary number system). Then we have a shorter character set (0 and 1) and the result is longer:
100110100100

But if we convert to hexadecimal number (base 16) with a character set of 16 (0-9 and A-F). Then we get a shorter result:
9A4

## Practice

So in your case we have the following character set for the input:

```
$inputCharacterSet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz=/-.&";
```

In total 41 characters: Numbers, lower cases and the special chars = / - . &

The character set for output is a bit tricky. We want use URL save characters only. I've grabbed them from here: [Characters allowed in GET parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter)

So our output character set is (73 characters):

```
$outputCharacterSet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz~-_.!*'(),$";
```

Numbers, lower *and* upper cases and some special characters.

We have more characters in our set for the output than for the input. Theory says we can short our input string. *Check*!

### Coding

Now we need an encode function from base 41 to base 73. For that case I don't know a PHP function. Luckily we can grab the function 'convBase' from here: *[Convert an arbitrarily large number from any base to any base](http://php.net/manual/de/function.base-convert.php#106546)*

```
<?php
function convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, $toBaseInput)
{
    if ($fromBaseInput == $toBaseInput) return $numberInput;
    $fromBase = str_split($fromBaseInput, 1);
    $toBase = str_split($toBaseInput, 1);
    $number = str_split($numberInput, 1);
    $fromLen = strlen($fromBaseInput);
    $toLen = strlen($toBaseInput);
    $numberLen = strlen($numberInput);
    $retval = '';
    if ($toBaseInput == '0123456789')
    {
        $retval = 0;
        for ($i = 1;$i <= $numberLen; $i++)
            $retval = bcadd($retval, bcmul(array_search($number[$i-1], $fromBase), bcpow($fromLen, $numberLen-$i)));
        return $retval;
    }
    if ($fromBaseInput != '0123456789')
        $base10 = convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, '0123456789');
    else
        $base10 = $numberInput;
    if ($base10<strlen($toBaseInput))
        return $toBase[$base10];
    while($base10 != '0')
    {
        $retval = $toBase[bcmod($base10,$toLen)] . $retval;
        $base10 = bcdiv($base10, $toLen, 0);
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

Now we can shorten the URL. The final code is:

```
$input = 'img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500';
$inputCharacterSet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz=/-.&";
$outputCharacterSet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz~-_.!*'(),$";
$encoded = convBase($input, $inputCharacterSet, $outputCharacterSet);
var_dump($encoded); // string(34) "BhnuhSTc7LGZv.h((Y.tG_IXIh8AR.$!t*"
$decoded = convBase($encoded, $outputCharacterSet, $inputCharacterSet);
var_dump($decoded); // string(39) "img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500"
```

**The encoded string has only 34 characters.**

## Optimizations

You can optimize the count of characters by

- reduce the length of input string. Do you really need the overhead of URL parameter syntax? Maybe you can format your string as follows:

`$input = '/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg,700,500';`

This reduces the input itself *and* the input character set. Your reduced input character set is then:

`$inputCharacterSet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/-.,";`

Final output:

`string(27) "E$AO.Y_JVIWMQ9BB_Xb3!Th*-Ut"`

`string(31) "/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg,700,500"`

- reducing the input character set ;-). Maybe you can exclude some more characters?
  You can encode the numbers to characters first. Then your input character set can be reduced by 10!
- increase your output character set. So the given set by me is googled within two minutes. Maybe you can use more URL save characters.

## Security

Heads up: There is no cryptographically logic in the code. So if somebody guesses the character sets, he/she can decode the string easily. But you can shuffle the character sets (once). Then it is a bit harder for the attacker, but not really safe. Maybe it’s enough for your use case anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of encoding the URL, output a thumbnail copy of the original image. Here's what I'm thinking:

1. Create a "map" for PHP by naming your pictures (the actual file names) using random characters. [Random_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) is a great place to start.
2. Embed the desired resolution within the randomized URL string from #1.
3. Use the [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) function to copy the original image into the resolution you would like to output before outputting it out to the client's device.

So for example:

1. Filename example (from `bin2hex(random_bytes(6))`): a1492fdbdcf2.jpg
2. Resolution desired: 800x600. My new link could look like:
   `http://myserver.com/?800a1492fdbdcf2600` or maybe `http://myserfer.com/?a1492800fdbdc600f2` or maybe even `http://myserver.com/?800a1492fdbdcf2=600` depending on where I choose to embed the resolution within the link
3. PHP would know that the file name is a1492fdbdcf2.jpg, grab it, use the imagecopyresampled to copy to the resolution you want, and output it.

Comment: Thanks. Renaming files is not an option, unfortunately

Comment: How about the whole path? since you consider only the file name to be encrypted

Answer (score 3):

Reading from the previous answers and below comments, you need a solution to hide the real path of your image parser, giving it a fixed image width.

#### Step 1: `http://www.example.com/tn/full/animals/images/lion.jpg`

You can achieve a basic "thumbnailer" by taking profit of `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule tn/(full|small)/(.*) index.php?size=$1&img=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Your PHP file:

```
 $basedir = "/public/content/";
 $filename = realpath($basedir.$_GET["img"]);

 ## Check that file is in $basedir
 if ((!strncmp($filename, $basedir, strlen($basedir))
    ||(!file_exists($filename)) die("Bad file path");

 switch ($_GET["size"]) {
    case "full":
        $width = 700;
        $height = 500;
        ## You can also use getimagesize() to test if the image is landscape or portrait
    break;
    default:
        $width = 350;
        $height = 250;
    break;
 }
 ## Here is your old code for resizing images.
 ## Note that the "tn" directory can exist and store the actual reduced images
```

This lets you using the URL `www.example.com/tn/full/animals/images/lion.jpg` to view your reduced in size image.

This has the advantage for [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) to preserve the original file name.

#### Step 2: `http://www.example.com/tn/full/lion.jpg`

If you want a shorter URL, if the number of images you have is not too much, you can use the basename of the file (e.g., "lion.jpg") and recursively search. When there is a collision, use an index to identify which one you want (e.g., "1--lion.jpg")

```
function matching_files($filename, $base) {
    $directory_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($base);
    $iterator       = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator);
    $regex_iterator = new RegexIterator($iterator, "#$filename\$#");
    $regex_iterator->setFlags(RegexIterator::USE_KEY);
    return array_map(create_function('$a', 'return $a->getpathName();'), iterator_to_array($regex_iterator, false));
}

function encode_name($filename) {
    $files = matching_files(basename($filename), realpath('public/content'));
    $tot = count($files);
    if (!$tot)
        return NULL;
    if ($tot == 1)
        return $filename;
    return "/tn/full/" . array_search(realpath($filename), $files) . "--" . basename($filename);
}

function decode_name($filename) {
    $i = 0;
    if (preg_match("#^([0-9]+)--(.*)#", $filename, $out)) {
        $i = $out[1];
        $filename = $out[2];
    }

    $files = matching_files($filename, realpath('public/content'));

    return $files ? $files[$i] : NULL;
}

echo $name = encode_name("gallery/animals/images/lion.jp‌​g").PHP_EOL;
 ## --> returns lion.jpg
 ## You can use with the above solution the URL http://www.example.com/tn/lion.jpg

 echo decode_name(basename($name)).PHP_EOL;
 ## -> returns the full path on disk to the image "lion.jpg"
```

---

**Original post:**

Basically, if you add some formatting in your example, your shortened URL is in fact longer:

```
img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500  // 39 characters

y8xNt9VPySwC44xM3aLUYt3M3HS9rIJ0tXJbcwMDtQxbUwMDAA // 50 characters
```

Using `base64_encode` will always result in longer strings. And `gzcompress` will require at less to store one occurrence of the different chars; this is not a good solution for small strings.

So doing nothing (or a simple `str_rot13`) is clearly the first option to consider if you want to shorten the result you had previously.

You can also use a simple character replacement method of your choice:

```
 $raw_query_string = 'img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500';
 $from = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&=/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 // The following line if the result of str_shuffle($from)
 $to = "0IQFwAKU1JT8BM5npNEdi/DvZmXuflPVYChyrL4R7xc&SoG3Hq6ks=e9jW2abtOzg";
 echo strtr($raw_query_string, $from, $to) . "\n";

 // Result: EDpL4MEu4MEu4NE-u5f-EDp.dmprYLU00rNLA00 // 39 characters
```

**Reading from your comment, you really want "to prevent anyone to gets a high-resolution image".**

The best way to achieve that is to generate a checksum with a private key.

Encode:

```
$secret = "ujoo4Dae";
$raw_query_string = 'img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500';
$encoded_query_string = $raw_query_string . "&k=" . hash("crc32", $raw_query_string . $secret);
```

Result: `img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500&k=2ae31804`

Decode:

```
if (preg_match("#(.*)&k=([^=]*)$#", $encoded_query_string, $out)
    && (hash("crc32", $out[1].$secret) == $out[2])) {
    $decoded_query_string = $out[1];
}
```

This does not hide the original path, but this path has no reason to be public. Your "index.php" can output your image from the local directory once the key has been checked.

If you really want to shorten your original URL, you have to consider the acceptable characters in the original URL to be restricted. Many compression methods are based on the fact that you can use a full byte to store more than a character.

Comment: The path isn't public on the site. I have already done it so that the urls are nice and SEO friendly: `www.mysite.com/gallery/animals/lion.jpg`. While the real path is: `/public/content/gallery/animals/images/lion.jpg`. Its loaded dynamically in the back-end by: `index.php?img=/public/content/gallery/animals/images/lion.jpg&w=700&h=500` - this link you can see only by opening dev tools or "share" image. The shorten url is necessary in case of "share", I mean e.g: *"share this image on facebook"* and so on. So I don't really like it to be query string formatted. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I edited my answer to add another way to do : using .htaccess to get a shorter url and then using recursive search to get a "shorterer" url.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to shorten URLs. You can look up how other services, like TinyURL, shorten their URLs. Here is a good article on hashes and shortening URLs: *[URL Shortening: Hashes In Practice](http://blog.codinghorror.com/url-shortening-hashes-in-practice/)*

You can use the PHP function [mhash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mhash.php) to apply hashes to strings.

And if you scroll down to "Available Hashes" on the mhash website, you can see what hashes you can use in the function (although I would check what PHP versions have which functions): *[mhash - Hash Library](http://mhash.sourceforge.net/mhash.3.html)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's very helpful, but do not suit my question, as I need non-DB solution (pure PHP).

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be better done by not obscuring at all. You could quite simply cache returned images and use a handler to provide them. This requires the image sizes to be hard coded into the PHP script. When you get new sizes, you can just delete everything in the cache as it is 'lazy loaded'.

**1. Get the image from the request**
This could be this: `/thumbnail.php?image=img.jpg&album=myalbum`. It could even be made to be anything using rewrite and have a URL like: `/gallery/images/myalbum/img.jpg`.

**2. Check to see if a temporary version does not exist**

You can do this using `is_file()`.

**3. Create it if it does not exist**

Use your current resizing logic to do it, but don't output the image. Save it to the temporary location.

**4. Read the temporary file contents to the stream**

It pretty much just outputs it.

Here is an **untested** code example...

```
<?php
    // Assuming we have a request /thumbnail.php?image=img.jpg&album=myalbum

    // These are temporary filenames places. You need to do this yourself on your system.
    $image = $_GET['image'];           // The file name
    $album = $_GET['album'];           // The album
    $temp_folder = sys_get_temp_dir(); // Temporary directory to store images
                                       // (this should really be a specific cache path)
    $image_gallery = "images";         // Root path to the image gallery

    $width = 700;
    $height = 500;

    $real_path = "$image_gallery/$album/$image";
    $temp_path = "$temp_folder/$album/$image";

    if(!is_file($temp_path))
    {
        // Read in the image
        $contents = file_get_contents($real_path);

        // Resize however you are doing it now.
        $thumb_contents = resizeImage($contents, $width, $height);

        // Write to the temporary file
        file_put_contents($temp_path, $thumb_contents);
    }

    $type = 'image/jpeg';
    header('Content-Type:' . $type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($temp_path));
    readfile($temp_path);
?>
```

Comment: `this would be better done by not obscuring at all` Yes, you're right. I had it done with SQL before (the whole app was based on DB). However now I need everything to be plug&play. It's painfull to support users that can't handle simple database configuration. Over 30% tickets I got was regarding SQL problems. I lost customers because they expect the app to work "right out of the box", even if they had no idea what their DB password is... No more rely on user's programming knowlegde. But I have to give them something that their images are safe. Somehow. I will look at your solution, thanks!

Comment: It's not a bad idea actually. I could make a "trigger" in the admin panel, so that user can simply recache all images at any time

Comment: @ArturFilipiak that's pretty much the gist. It will also save CPU time as the image only has to be cached once. This is exactly how Wordpress and other CMS's do it. You could also add some extra headers to allow the images to be client side cached - especially if you take the rewrite route - as the path will look like a real static image.

Comment: Isn't a space missing after `Content-Type:`? [An example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_syntax).

Answer (score 2):

### Short words about "security"

You simply won't be able to secure your link if there is no "secret password" stored somewhere: as long as the URI carries all information to access your resource, then it will be decodable and your "custom security" (they are opposite words btw) will be broken easily.

You can still put a salt in your PHP code (like `$mysalt="....long random string..."`) since I doubt you want an eternal security (such approach is weak because you cannot renew the `$mysalt` value, but in your case, a few years security sounds sufficient, since anyway, a user can buy one picture and share it elsewhere, breaking any of your security mechanism).

If you want to have a safe mechanism, use a well-known one (as a framework would carry), along with authentication and user rights management mechanism (so you can know who's looking for your image, and whether they are allowed to).

Security has a cost. If you don't want to afford its computing and storing requirements, then forget about it.

---

### Secure by signing the URL

If you want to avoid users easy by-passing and get full resolution picture, then you may just sign the URI (but really, for safety, use something that already exist instead of that quick draft example below):

```
$salt = '....long random stirng...';
$params = array('img' => '...', 'h' => '...', 'w' => '...');
$p = http_build_query($params);
$check = password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('salt' => $salt, 'cost' => 1000);
$uri = http_build_query(array_merge($params, 'sig' => $check));
```

Decoding:

```
$sig = $_GET['sig'];
$params = $_GET;
unset($params['sig']);

// Same as previous
$salt = '....long random stirng...';
$p = http_build_query($params);
$check = password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('salt' => $salt, 'cost' => 1000);
if ($sig !== $check) throw new DomainException('Invalid signature');
```

See *[password_hash](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.password-hash.php)*

---

### Shorten smartly

"Shortening" with a generic compression algorithm is useless here because the headers will be longer than the URI, so it will almost never shorten it.

If you want to shorten it, be smart: don't give the relative path (`/dir/dir`) if it's always the same (or give it only if it's not the main one). Don't give the extension if it's always the same (or give it when it's not `png` if almost everything is in `png`). Don't give the `height` because the image carries the `aspect ratio`: you only need the `width`. Give it in `x100px` if you do not need a pixel-accurate width.

Answer (score 2):

A lot has been said about how encoding doesn't help security, so I am just concentrating on the shortening and aesthetics.

Rather than thinking of it as a string, you could consider it as three individual components.  Then if you limit your code space for each component, you can pack things together a lot smaller.

E.g.,

- **path** - Only consisting of the 26 characters (a-z) and  / - . (Variable length)
- **width** - Integer (0 - 65k) (Fixed length, 16 bits)
- **height** - Integer (0 - 65k) (Fixed length, 16 bits)

I'm limiting the path to only consist of a maximum 31 characters, so we can use five bit groupings.

Pack your fixed length dimensions first, and append each path character as five bits.  It might also be necessary to add a special null character to fill up the end byte.  Obviously you need to use the same dictionary string for encoding and decoding.

See the code below.

This shows that by limiting what you encode and how much you can encode, you can get a shorter string.  You could make it even shorter by using only 12 bit dimension integers (max 2048), or even removing parts of the path if they are known such as base path or file extension (see last example).

```
<?php

function encodeImageAndDimensions($path, $width, $height) {
    $dictionary = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/-."); // Maximum 31 characters, please

    if ($width >= pow(2, 16)) {
        throw new Exception("Width value is too high to encode with 16 bits");
    }
    if ($height >= pow(2, 16)) {
        throw new Exception("Height value is too high to encode with 16 bits");
    }

    // Pack width, then height first
    $packed = pack("nn", $width, $height);

    $path_bits = "";
    foreach (str_split($path) as $ch) {
        $index = array_search($ch, $dictionary, true);
        if ($index === false) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot encode character outside of the allowed dictionary");
        }

        $index++; // Add 1 due to index 0 meaning NULL rather than a.

        // Work with a bit string here rather than using complicated binary bit shift operators.
        $path_bits .= str_pad(base_convert($index, 10, 2), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    // Remaining space left?
    $modulo = (8 - (strlen($path_bits) % 8)) %8;

    if ($modulo >= 5) {
        // There is space for a null character to fill up to the next byte
        $path_bits .= "00000";
        $modulo -= 5;
    }

    // Pad with zeros
    $path_bits .= str_repeat("0", $modulo);

    // Split in to nibbles and pack as a hex string
    $path_bits = str_split($path_bits, 4);
    $hex_string = implode("", array_map(function($bit_string) {
        return base_convert($bit_string, 2, 16);
    }, $path_bits));
    $packed .= pack('H*', $hex_string);

    return base64_url_encode($packed);
}

function decodeImageAndDimensions($str) {
    $dictionary = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/-.");

    $data = base64_url_decode($str);

    $decoded = unpack("nwidth/nheight/H*path", $data);

    $path_bit_stream = implode("", array_map(function($nibble) {
        return str_pad(base_convert($nibble, 16, 2), 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }, str_split($decoded['path'])));

    $five_pieces = str_split($path_bit_stream, 5);

    $real_path_indexes = array_map(function($code) {
        return base_convert($code, 2, 10) - 1;
    }, $five_pieces);

    $real_path = "";
    foreach ($real_path_indexes as $index) {
        if ($index == -1) {
            break;
        }
        $real_path .= $dictionary[$index];
    }

    $decoded['path'] = $real_path;

    return $decoded;
}

// These do a bit of magic to get rid of the double equals sign and obfuscate a bit.  It could save an extra byte.
function base64_url_encode($input) {
    $trans = array('+' => '-', '/' => ':', '*' => '$', '=' => 'B', 'B' => '!');
    return strtr(str_replace('==', '*', base64_encode($input)), $trans);
}
function base64_url_decode($input) {
    $trans = array('-' => '+', ':' => '/', '$' => '*', 'B' => '=', '!' => 'B');
    return base64_decode(str_replace('*', '==', strtr($input, $trans)));
}

// Example usage

$encoded = encodeImageAndDimensions("/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg", 700, 500);
var_dump($encoded); // string(27) "Arw!9NkTLZEy2hPJFnxLT9VA4A$"
$decoded = decodeImageAndDimensions($encoded);
var_dump($decoded); // array(3) { ["width"] => int(700) ["height"] => int(500) ["path"] => string(23) "/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg" }

$encoded = encodeImageAndDimensions("/another/example/image.png", 4500, 2500);
var_dump($encoded); // string(28) "EZQJxNhc-iCy2XAWwYXaWhOXsHHA"
$decoded = decodeImageAndDimensions($encoded);
var_dump($decoded); // array(3) { ["width"] => int(4500) ["height"] => int(2500) ["path"] => string(26) "/another/example/image.png" }

$encoded = encodeImageAndDimensions("/short/eg.png", 300, 200);
var_dump($encoded); // string(19) "ASwAyNzQ-VNlP2DjgA$"
$decoded = decodeImageAndDimensions($encoded);
var_dump($decoded); // array(3) { ["width"] => int(300) ["height"] => int(200) ["path"] => string(13) "/short/eg.png" }

$encoded = encodeImageAndDimensions("/very/very/very/very/very-hyper/long/example.png", 300, 200);
var_dump($encoded); // string(47) "ASwAyN2LLO7FlndiyzuxZZ3Yss8Rm!ZbY9x9lwFsGF7!xw$"
$decoded = decodeImageAndDimensions($encoded);
var_dump($decoded); // array(3) { ["width"] => int(300) ["height"] => int(200) ["path"] => string(48) "/very/very/very/very/very-hyper/long/example.png" }

$encoded = encodeImageAndDimensions("only-file-name", 300, 200);
var_dump($encoded); //string(19) "ASwAyHuZnhksLxwWlA$"
$decoded = decodeImageAndDimensions($encoded);
var_dump($decoded); // array(3) { ["width"] => int(300) ["height"] => int(200) ["path"] => string(14) "only-file-name" }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question you state that it should be pure PHP and not use a database, and there should be a possibility to decode the strings. So bending the rules a bit:

- The way I am interpreting this question is that we don't care about security that much but, we do want the shortest hashes that lead back to images.
- We can also take "decode possibility" with a pinch of salt by using a one way hashing algorithm.
- We can store the hashes inside a JSON object, then store the data in a file, so all we have to do at the end of the day is string matching

```

```
class FooBarHashing {

    private $hashes;

    private $handle;

    /**
     * In producton this should be outside the web root
     * to stop pesky users downloading it and geting hold of all the keys.
     */
    private $file_name = './my-image-hashes.json';

    public function __construct() {
        $this->hashes = $this->get_hashes();
    }

    public function get_hashes() {
        // Open or create a file.
        if (! file_exists($this->file_name)) {
            fopen($this->file_name, "w");
        }
        $this->handle = fopen($this->file_name, "r");


        $hashes = [];
        if (filesize($this->file_name) > 0) {
            $contents = fread($this->handle, filesize($this->file_name));
            $hashes = get_object_vars(json_decode($contents));
        }

        return $hashes;
    }

    public function __destroy() {
        // Close the file handle
        fclose($this->handle);
    }

    private function update() {
        $handle = fopen($this->file_name, 'w');
        $res = fwrite($handle, json_encode($this->hashes));
        if (false === $res) {
            //throw new Exception('Could not write to file');
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function add_hash($image_file_name) {
        $new_hash = md5($image_file_name, false);

        if (! in_array($new_hash, array_keys($this->hashes) ) ) {
            $this->hashes[$new_hash] =  $image_file_name;
            return $this->update();
        }

        //throw new Exception('File already exists');
    }

    public function resolve_hash($hash_string='') {
        if (in_array($hash_string, array_keys($this->hashes))) {
            return $this->hashes[$hash_string];
        }

        //throw new Exception('File not found');
    }
}
```

```

Usage example:

```
<?php
// Include our class
require_once('FooBarHashing.php');
$hashing = new FooBarHashing;

// You will need to add the query string you want to resolve first.
$hashing->add_hash('img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500');

// Then when the user requests the hash the query string is returned.
echo $hashing->resolve_hash('65992be720ea3b4d93cf998460737ac6');
```

So the end result is a string that is only **32** chars long, which is way shorter than the **52** we had before.

Comment: Yes, we're closer to the solution. I use actualy files to store images data as a JSON object, like: `name`, `title`, `description`... I'll look at your solution, thanks

Comment: Oh dear. This answer is an extremely inefficient implementation of a hash table using a json file as storage (AKA a database).  This would probably end up being slower than using a real database when you get a few thousand records in there.  Think about all that parsing on every request.  Think about I/O wait and concurrency.  Not a good solution.

Comment: @Phil_1984_, JSON file (on first load) along with a localStorage.

Comment: @Phil_1984_, I would disagree with it being inefficient compared to a "real" database due to I/O since we only read the file once, then cache the hash table in memory. I would expect my solution to be used as a singleton and multiple look-ups to be done at once. However you are correct that parsing JSON is expensive in PHP, so a CSV would be a better option.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the usage scenario, but speaking purely about PHP now... Even if you use it as a singleton, 1 singleton would get constructed for every single request which uses the library (e.g. image request).  If 10 different users request different images at the same time, each url needs to get decoded and since there is no shared memory (unless you use something like memcache) each will have to read and parse the file.

Comment: What is the gist of it? What and how is it doing for the hashing? What kind hashing is it using? Can you add it to your answer? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39938533/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, you won't be able to shorten the query string better than any known
compression algorithm. As mentioned in other answers, a compressed
version will be shorter by a few (around 4-6) characters than the original.
Moreover, the original string can be decoded relatively easy (opposed to decoding [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) or [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), for instance).

I suggest shortening URLs by means of Web server configuration. You might
shorten it further by replacing image path with an ID (store *ID-filename*
pairs in a database).

For example, the following [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) configuration accepts
URLs like `/t/123456/700/500/4fc286f1a6a9ac4862bdd39a94a80858`, where

- the first number (`123456`) is supposed to be an image ID from database;
- `700` and `500` are image dimensions;
- the last part is an *MD5 hash protecting from requests with different dimensions*.

```
# Adjust maximum image size
# image_filter_buffer 5M;

server {
  listen          127.0.0.13:80;
  server_name     img-thumb.local;

  access_log /var/www/img-thumb/logs/access.log;
  error_log /var/www/img-thumb/logs/error.log info;

  set $root "/var/www/img-thumb/public";

  # /t/image_id/width/height/md5
  location ~* "(*UTF8)^/t/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})$" {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm-img-thumb.sock;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING image_id=$1&w=$2&h=$3&hash=$4;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/img-thumb/public/t/resize.php;

    image_filter resize $2 $3;
    error_page 415 = /empty;

    break;
  }

  location = /empty {
    empty_gif;
  }

  location / { return 404; }
}
```

The server accepts only URLs of specified pattern, forwards request to `/public/t/resize.php` script with modified query string, then resizes the image generated by PHP with the [`image_filter`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html) module. In case of error, returns an empty GIF image.

The `image_filter` is optional, and it is included only as an example. Resizing can be performed fully on PHP side. With Nginx, it is possible to get rid of PHP part, by the way.

The PHP script is supposed to validate the hash as follows:

```
// Store this in some configuration file.
$salt = '^sYsdfc_sd&9wa.';

$w = $_GET['w'];
$h = $_GET['h'];

$true_hash = md5($w . $h . $salt . $image_id);
if ($true_hash != $_GET['hash']) {
  die('invalid hash');
}

$filename = fetch_image_from_database((int)$_GET['image_id']);
$img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion in the comments section it looks like what you really want is to protect your original high-resolution images.

Having that in mind, I'd suggest to actually do that first using your web server configuration (e.g., Apache [mod_authz_core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) or Nginx [ngx_http_access_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#deny)) to deny access from the web to the directory where your original images are stored.

Note that the server will only deny access to your images from the web, but you will still be able to access them directly from your PHP scripts. Since you already are displaying images using some "resizer" script I'd suggest putting some hard limit there and refuse to resize images to anything bigger then that (e.g., something like `$width = min(1000, $_GET['w'])`).

I know this does not answer your original question, but I think this would the right solution to protect your images. And if you still want to obfuscate the original name and resizing parameters you can do that however you see fit without worrying that someone might figure out what’s behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the resulting URL can be shortened much more than in your own example. But I suggest a few steps to obfuscate your images better.

First I would remove everything you can from the base URL you are zipping and Base64 encoding, so instead of

> img=/dir/dir/hi-res-img.jpg&w=700&h=500

I would use

> s=hi-res-img.jpg,700,500,062c02153d653119

Were those last 16 chars are a hash to validate the URL being opened is the same you offered in your code - and the user is not trying to trick the high-resolution image out of the system.

Your index.php that serves the images would start like this:

```
function myHash($sRaw) { // returns a 16-characters dual hash
    return hash('adler32', $sRaw) . strrev(hash('crc32', $sRaw));
} // These two hash algorithms are suggestions, there are more for you to chose.

// s=hi-res-img.jpg,700,500,062c02153d653119
$aParams = explode(',', $_GET['s']);
if (count($aParams) != 4) {
    die('Invalid call.');
}

list($sFileName, $iWidth, $iHeight, $sHash) = $aParams;

$sRaw = session_id() . $sFileName . $iWidth . $iHeight;
if ($sHash != myHash($sRaw)) {
    die('Invalid hash.');
}
```

After this point you can send the image as the user opening it had access to a valid link.

Note the use of *session_id* as part of the raw string that makes the hash is optional, but would make it impossible for users to share a valid URL - as it would be session bind. *If you want the URLs to be shareable, then just remove session_id from that call.*

I would wrap the resulting URL the same way you already do, zip + Base64. The result would be even bigger than your version, but more difficult to see through the obfuscation, and therefore protecting your images from unauthorised downloads.

If you want only to make it shorter, I do not see a way of doing it without renaming the files (or their folders), or without the use of a database.

The file database solution proposed will surely create problems of concurrency - unless you always have no or very few people using the system simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want the size there, so that if you decide some day that the preview images are too small, you want to increase the size - the solution here is to hard code the image size into the PHP script and eliminate it from the URL.

If you want to change the size in the future, change the hardcoded values in the PHP script (or in a *config.php* file that you include into the script).

You've also said that you are already using files to store image data as a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object, like: `name`, `title`, `description`. Exploiting this, you don't need a database and can use the JSON file name as the key for looking up the image data.

When the user visits a URL like this:

```
www.mysite.com/share/index.php?ax9v
```

You load `ax9v.json` from the location you are already storing the JSON files, and within that JSON file the image's real path is stored. Then load the image, resize it according to the hardcoded size in your script and send it to the user.

Drawing from the conclusions in
*[URL Shortening: Hashes In Practice](https://blog.codinghorror.com/url-shortening-hashes-in-practice/)*, to get the smallest search string part of the URL you would need to iterate valid character combinations as new files are uploaded (e.g., the first one is "AAA" then "AAB", "AAC", etc.) instead of using a hashing algorithm.

Your solution would then have only three characters in the string for the first 238,328 photos you upload.

I had started to prototype a PHP solution on [PhpFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_online_source_code_playgrounds#Online_web_client-side_source_code_playgrounds), but the code disappeared (don't use PhpFiddle).