# Python requests and html char encode

Tags: python, rest, encoding, request

I get a failure in GET/POST whenever I use html escape chars in my payload 
e.g. in this case amp -  `&`

```
url = 'https://myserver/?filter={"arr": {"$in": ["me and you", "me & you"]}}'


res = reqSession.get(url, verify=False)
```

that resolve:

```
https%3A//myserver/%3Ffilter%3D%7B%22arr%22%3A%20%7B%22%24in%22%3A%20%5B%22me%20and%20you%22%2C%20%22me%20%26%20you%22%5D%7D%7D
```

if I use the urllib.quote('&') on the char it's working but If I do it on the entire url string the requests failed with `Invalid url error`

I also tried to put `headers={'Content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}` in the get method but that didn't helped me as well

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [This responses on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter) you cannot use & in the HTTP parameter - it is reserved.

Comment: this still not answering how do I do it without escaping each char using requests