# ASP.NET core FromQuery getting invalid parameters with dot sign inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to send some parameters with GET request to the controller in query string. I am getting all parameters that are inside query string to one `Dictionary<string, string>` using `[FromQuery]`. It is working well until one of the parameter name contains dot (`.`) sign. I checked `Request.Query` object and it looks that it's parsed well but my Dictionary object get this one, exact item wrong. So it looks like bug in `[FromQuery]` binder or i am doing something wrong. Code with debbuged values of `Request.Query` and mine `parameters` below:[image]

This is how the query string that is sent looks like:
`?query=&InspectionType=Safety&ItemType=InspectionPoint&RecordParentGUID=9275bee2-0a2d-461c-8835-51880e76f035&parent.ResultClassCode=parent.ResultClassCode`

UPDATE:
Got answer from Eilon Lipton working in .net developers team, in short - this is by design. Dot sign `.` and `[`, `]` are special ones used for denoting properties and indexers. Full answer available here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6746

Comment: Indeed, you should file a bug report in http://github.com/aspnet/mvc. You have a look at the code for DictionaryModelBinderProvider, this is the class responsible for binding to a dictionary.

Comment: @MichalHainc I found that dot sign is unreserved characters so don't need to encode them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter

Comment: One thing worth noting is that the GUID is picking up correct value. only the other ones (probably Enums) are not picking any values. event the last one which is a string, picks up the value

Comment: @Gurpreet all of this parameters are strings, they come from ajax call in js. I used Dictionary<string, string> not to bind it to any other type but as you see still when a key have a dot sign - it breaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The . (dot), [ and ] characters are used everywhere internally by ASP.NET MVC Core as path separators in the model binding process and there is (AFAIK) no way around that.

If you want to access the raw values from the query string, `Request.Query` is by far the simplest solution.

To turn it into a pure `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
Request.Query.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what i already did. Thought that maybe that some kind of bug inside binder itself.

Comment: Accepted this as a workaround, already create issue on github for that problem but no response yet. Will update if get any new info about that.

Comment: @JacobSobus, can you share the url to the issue here?

Comment: @MladenB. it is in my question at the end :) Here You go: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6746

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a partial view to flatten parent.ResultClassCode to ResultClassCode?

The partial could look like this

```
@model parent
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ResultClassCode"></label><span asp-validation-for="ResultClassCode" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input asp-for="ResultClassCode" class="form-control">
</div>
```