# Express routing matching extra URL tokens

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I would like to get URLs of the form (strictly) `/forumId/slug/` with Express' `router.get()`. Additional tokens should result in a 404.

I came up with this path route: `/:forumId([^?\/]{0,}):parameters1?/:slug([^?\/]{0,})?:parameters2?` which according to `express-route-tester` behaves as expected.

However Express seems to also be catching paths with extra tokens after the slug. Directly passing a Javascript regular expression instead of a string has the same effect.

Here is the regex I used: `/^\/(\d+)(?:\?[^\?\/]{0,})?(?:$|\/([^\?\/]{0,})(?:\?[^\?\/]{0,})?\/?$)/`

Examples of strings that should match (those work):

```
/7721
/7721/
/7721?page=2
/7721/ForumTitle/
/7721/AnotherForumTitle?test/
/7721/YetAnotherForumTitle?page=2
/7721?page=3/ForumTitle?page=2
/7721?page=3/ForumTitle?page=2/
```

Example of strings that shouldn't match:

```
/7721?page=3/ForumTitle?page=2/threadId
```

Express uses `path-to-regexp` to parse the string and according to the docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#user-content-usage), the 'end' option is set to true by default which seems to corroborate that the match should stop right after the slug.

What am I missing?

The version of Express is 4.16.4.

UPDATE: removing the part about the query parameters (?page=2) in the regex solved the problem. Why is that so? Was my regex flawed (I tried spotting possible greedy matches but couldn't find one) or is this expected from `path-to-regexp`?

Comment: Try this https://regexr.com/44hu7 and also remember about `^` and `$` operators for limit line.

Comment: @IhorVoronin 'ForumTitle' is just an example of title but could be any series of characters. I edited the question to include the regex I used that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in Express routing docs,

> query strings are not part of the route path

(https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths).

The part trying to catch the query parameters in `/^\/(\d+)(?:\?[^\?\/]{0,})?(?:$|\/([^\?\/]{0,})(?:\?[^\?\/]{0,})?\/?$)/` was therefore unnecessary, resulting in the simplified `/^\/(\d{1,})(?:$|\/([^\/]{0,})\/?$)/`:

- `^\/`: beginning of the endpoint followed by a slash '/'
- `(\d{1,})`: the forum identifier consisting of digits
- `(?:$|\/([^\/]{0,})\/?$)/`: either ends there or captures an optional slug

This regex matched every provided example but also captured `/7721/ForumTitle?page=2/test` which should result in a 404. Upon further investigation I noticed '/test' was being captured as part of the query parameters in req.query (`{"page": "2/test"}`).

This is odd, since the slash '/' is supposed to be a reserved character for delimitation ([Characters allowed in GET parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter#answer-1455639)). Additional information would be helpful.

EDIT: to quote Douglas Wilson (from [there](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3820)), `Express.js uses Node.js core to parse the paths according to the url spec`. Node.js's `URL` module follows the [WHATWG URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urls).