# Does the string "php?id=1" within a http GET request mean there is necesseraly an sql request to a back-end database?

Tags: php

In order to find websites with potential sql injections, it is possible to use google dorks like `"inurl:.php?id="`

From the results that google will give, does it mean all the websites listed use sql database (mysql, oracle or any other)?

Comment: It's a safe assumption but not guaranteed.

Comment: What about NoSQL databases?

Comment: Does Codelgniter Web framework use sql database ?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

As it is a backend call, we can't exactly say, that it related to a Database as well. The reason is that while captured based on `$_GET['id']`, the returning value can be decided only upon the backend, solely based on PHP. So SQL connection is not essentially needed in that purpose.

Comment: Thank you. It could be a php include for example ?

Comment: Yes it could be, and we can just render it via the same script without a including a separate script.

Comment: Which means even if I know for sure the website is using an sql back-end database, the fact that an HTTP GET Request would show that string ".php?id=" doesn't necessarily mean the request will be send to the sql database. It just could use another way : include fonction, XML, etc...

Comment: Yep exactly. But in most cases this would be DB server integrated.

Comment: So, to be sure it is using sql I need to play with the value like 2-1 or 1+' '+1 or stuff like that to see how it is treated by the application. I am asking because many times when I try to do something like id=20 then id=20-1 for exemple it will throw the same result. I suspect it is not using sql.

Comment: Regarding that I do think this would give a proper explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter