# Golang r.URL.Query("x") does not return the full value with special characters

Tags: go

I was using  **r.URL.Query("model")** to retrieve a url param. Lets say **"https://example.com?model=345;1"**
My expected behaviour is to retrieve: **345;1**
But I only receive: **345**
Is there a specific meaning behind it? and how i can force to get the full value. I am quite new go.

[Code example](https://play.golang.org/p/b50pivsgXoj)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Characters allowed in GET parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter)

Comment: [Do not post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please read [ask] to get the most out of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As LeGEC indicated the problem is due the fact that the semi-colon (;) is a character that has (or could have) special meaning in URLs.

You can use "%#v" in your Go Printf example to see how Go parsed the query string:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/url"
import "log"

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("https://example.com?model=345;1")
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    q := u.Query()
    fmt.Printf("%#v",q)
}
```

Gives

```
url.Values{"1":[]string{""}, "model":[]string{"345"}}
```

You could use `u.RawQuery` to get the entire string "model=345;1" and then parse it yourself. Not ideal, but perhaps a quick workaround.