# My link URLs are changing

Tags: java, html, jsp, url-encoding, application-server

In my web portal, for some users (not all), when they click to a link, the `'&'` characters become `'+'`.

For example, the link is :
`www.mysite.com/test.jsp?param1=test1&param2=test2` ,

Then it becomes : 
`www.mysite.com/test.jsp?param1=test1+param2=test2`

It only happens for a specific country (Brazil). My other portals with same code work correctly.

I thought to handle request with servlet and when I see `"+"` replace with `"&"` but it is not a proper solution I think..

Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a valid URL query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373504/what-is-a-valid-url-query-string)

Comment: You may have to adapt your query string parsing accordingly. The cited RFC should be consulted, but it doesn't say you must use & or cannot use +.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/) core tag `c:url`

This tag automatically performs URL rewriting when necessary. The JSTL url tag is just an alternative method of writing the call to the `response.encodeURL()` method. The only real advantage the url tag provides is proper URL encoding, including any parameters specified by children param tag.

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:url value="/test.jsp" var="url">
    <c:param name="param1" value="test1" />
    <c:param name="param2" value="test2" />
</c:url>

<a href="${url }">Click Here</a>
```