# Query string get modified automatically by the browser how to get unmodified one?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, query-string

I am having an issue with query string. i send an activation link to email that link have a query string for example a user activation token. Her is an example of the link `http://localhost:3000/#/activation?activation_code=27kVNlC4ShWuL4pkH3/FhVA==`.However when i click on the link the browser automatically modify the query string to be `http://localhost:3000/#/activation?activation_code=27kVNlC4ShWuL4pkH3%2FhVA`which results in encryption error. Any idea how i can get the actual query string. i am using angular as front end and asp.net web API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activation code you are embedding in your url is using reserved characters. See this question: [What is a valid URL query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373504/what-is-a-valid-url-query-string)

I would suggest you url encode the activation token before appending it to the url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL encode your token. It's using reserved characters.

Don't forget to use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode all special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Server.UrlDecode(activation_code)
```