# Query string degenerate cases

Tags: regex, http, url, query-string, querystringparameter

I am looking around looking for a correct regualr expression for validating URI query strings. I found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373504/what-is-a-valid-url-query-string) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959352/validate-url-query-string-with-regex) but I still have doubts on the edge cases, where the key or the value could be empty. For example, should be the following treated as valid query strings?

```
?&&
?=
?a=
?a=&
?=a
?&=a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am looking [...] for a correct regular expression for [valid] URI query strings.

Sure thing, no prob. As per [RFC 3986, appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B), here it is:

```
^([^#]*)$
```

If you want something more elaborate, you can check [section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) for the allowed characters in addition to percent-encoded entities. The regex would look something like this:

```
^(%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[[:print:]])*$
```

As far as RFC 3986 is concerned, all your examples are valid so far. The RFC is telling us how the query string has to be *encoded* while saying little about how the query string has to be *structured*. Older RFCs are continuously shifting authority over the structure of query strings between CGI and HTTP without ever formally specifying a grammar (see e.g. [RFC 3875, sec. 4.1.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.7), [RFC 2396, sec. 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.4), [RFC 1808, sec. 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3), …).

An interesting note can be found in [RFC 7230, section 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7320#section-2.4):

> Applications MUST NOT directly specify the syntax of queries, as this can cause operational difficulties for deployments that do not support a particular form of a query.
> […]
> [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224) constrains the syntax of query strings used in form submission.  New form languages SHOULD NOT emulate it, but instead allow creation of a broader variety of URIs

For a full validity check on such query strings, you would have to implement the [algorithm for decoding formdata](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-decoding-algorithm) recommended by the W3C. Could be done in regex, but I would advise against it for reasons of sanity.

With regard to your examples: I believe they are all valid. How they are interpreted should be left to the receiving application. Some are not as much of a fringe case as you may think, though: `?&&` is simply an empty dictionary while `?=a` could map to `{ "": "a" }`.

Comment: Promising future standard [here](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#application/x-www-form-urlencoded)...

Comment: @FranklinYu I've seen that. However, it bears mentioning that this is a "living standard" which does not seek to *replace* RFC 3986. If at all, it is augmenting it.