# Underscores vs dashes in HTTP parameter names

Tags: forms, http, web, url-parameters, http-parameters

I'm familiar with the convention of using hyphens to separate words in URL paths. What about parameter names, such as within a `<form>`:

```html
<form>
  <input name="my_special_field">
</form>
```

is that better or `my-special-field`? I've seen Google use underscores in analytics with `utm_campaign` and other parameter names. Underscores read a little better and allow for the occasional hyphen within the name (`field_for_5-16-17`). But hyphens are certainly the convention for URL paths.

What's the convention for separating words in an HTTP parameter name?

Comment: Didn't know about that syntax highlighting feature @DaSourcerer, thanks!

Comment: [few do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What's the convention for separating words in an HTTP parameter name?

Well, I think there is none. I hear hyphens perform a bit better SEO-wise. But as long as you are compliant with [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (especially [section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)), everything is okay.

If it really interests you, part of the dilemma is that the query string has [never been formalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42069013/query-string-degenerate-cases). There is only a consensus on which characters are supposed to be allowed in it.