# Multiple values for field names in a URL query string?

Tags: python, query-string, standards, urllib, specifications

Python3's `urllib.parse.parse_qs` oddly returns a dictionary of `string, list<string>` for query strings:

```
>>> import urllib.parse as p
>>> url = p.urlparse("http://exam.ple/path?query=string&yes=no")
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='exam.ple', path='/path', params='', query='query=string&yes=no', fragment='')

>>> p.parse_qs(url.query)
{'query': ['string'], 'yes': ['no']}
```

The function's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) says that:

> The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values are lists of values for each name.

Can I take advantage of this "lists of values" capability somehow?

Neither [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), nor [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13373504/4532996), nor [the IETF specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) mention anything about "multiple" or "lists" of values for fields, and I can't find any such syntax:

```
>>> p.parse_qs(p.urlparse("http://exam.ple/path?query=string&yes=no/a=0").query)
{'query': ['string'], 'yes': ['no/a=0']}
>>> p.parse_qs(p.urlparse("http://exam.ple/path?query=string@yes=no").query)
{'query': ['string@yes=no']}
>>> p.parse_qs(p.urlparse("http://exam.ple/path?query=string;yes=no").query)
{'query': ['string'], 'yes': ['no']}
>>> p.parse_qs(p.urlparse("http://exam.ple/path?query=string,yes=no").query)
{'query': ['string,yes=no']}
```

No separator character seems to ever result in a key with a value containing more than one string. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will get a list longer than 1 element if there is a repeated query key:

```
>>> url = p.urlparse("http://exam.ple/path?query=string1&query=string2")
>>> p.parse_qs(url.query)
{'query': ['string1', 'string2']}
```

Comment: That's...weird but ok