# How to get the value of a Query String which includes an ampersand &?

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.querystring

I need to retrieve the value of a query string for a department using .net c# but as some of the department names include an '&' as soon as it is read it stops after the &

```
www.example.co.uk/default.aspx?dept=IM&T

Label1.Text = "The Department is - " + Request.QueryString["dept"];
```

The result is...

> The Department is - IM

How can I get this to read the query string as `IM&T`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman because is asp.net the duplicate is not the one you set. The encoding is done using the `Server.URLEncode` and the decode is automatic done on `QueryString[]` call

Comment: hi @PatrickHofman - I have tried what you have suggested - Label3.Text = Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["Dept"]); but it is still having the same issue and stopping as soon as it hits the &. The question which you have linked through didnt seem to help with my issue... As I am linking from one page with a gridview of items and passing the id with a querystring to another page showing a break down of the depts for the selected item i am unable to just change the & in the query string to %26.

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue - where I am picking up the department set as a query string I have used the replace method to replace & with %26 this then allows the gridview to read the query string parameter.

Answer (score 2):

[escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

To use "&" as URL query string, simply changes it to `%26` percent-encoding. `&amp;` is used for HTML encoding.

Comment: No need to link the duplicate, just flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: Tetsuya: If I can give you 10 upvotes, I will!  It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode an &  (ampersand) in a query sting to %26

Here is a helpful tool to help: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

And a good thread on the rules on when to escape:

[What characters must be escaped in an HTTP query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322764/what-characters-must-be-escaped-in-an-http-query-string)