# Should I encode names of parameters in a query string of a URI?

Tags: http, uri, url-parameters, percent-encoding

I know I need to encode the arguments of parameters in a query string of a URI, but what about the parameter names, **do they need to be encoded too**?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why parameter name would need to be encoded. I am struggling with the same question, and so far nothing came up in my searches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Special characters in query strings have their special meaning *anywhere* in the query string.

If the parameter name is `foo=bar` then `?foo=bar=something` won't be parsed as `foo=bar` equals `something`.

Comment: *"won't be parsed"* - it depends on the parsing implementation, isn't it (hypothetically, a parsing implementation may decide that for each query string parameter all `=` except the last one are ignored)? after all, `=` is [allowed unencoded in a query string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31300627/3002584).