# Python Bottle.Routes. Capturing a question mark (?)

Tags: python, regex, bottle

In a bookmarking app. in Bottle I'm trying to capture a link which is appended to a URL.

But when I'm trying to send a YouTube URL, eg.

```
http://myapp.com/bookmark/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZOPGKFsTzI
```

Even the route

```
@route("/bookmark/<url:re:.+>")
def save(url) :
    ...
```

won't capture it.

It captures the *https://www.youtube.com/watch* but stops at the ?

Any ideas on a pattern to match this?

Comment: `'http://myapp.com/bookmark/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZOPGKFsTzI'.split('/bookmark/')[1]`

Comment: I'm not processing the string manually. This is in Bottle.routes. So that is being done for me behind the scenes. That's why I can't, for example, transform the string before it goes into the regex test.

Comment: Your example url is, arguably, flawed. At a minimum, the question mark should be escaped, to distinguish myapps.com's args from youtube.com's args. Some [useful discussion is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322764/what-characters-must-be-escaped-in-an-http-query-string) and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ?... part is likely not considered part of the url by the Bottle framework, but as part of the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

You can set a route for bookmark/.*, and then access the request object to get the complete string.

Comment: You've got the right idea, but to be precise: the question mark is indeed a part of the url; it delineates the _path_ component from the _query string_ component.