# Tomcat: possible to parse URL parameters containing '&'?

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6

I have a servlet running on tomcat 6 which should be called as follows:

```
http://<server>/Address/Details?summary="Acme & co"
```

However: when I iterate through the parameters in the servlet code:

```
//...
while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    paramName = (String) paramNames.nextElement();
    if (paramName.equals("summary")) {
        summary = request.getParameter(paramName).toString();
    }
}
//...
```

the value of `summary` is `"Acme "`.

I assume tomcat ignores the quotes - so it sees `"& co"` as a second parameter (albeit improperly formed: there's no `=...`).

So: is there any way to avoid this?  I want the value of `summary` to be `"Acme & co"`.  I tried replacing '&' in the URL with `&amp;` but that doesn't work (presumably because it's decoded back to a straight '&' before the params are parsed out).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `http://<server>/Address/Details?summary="Acme %26 co"`. Because in URL special http symbol(e.g. &,/, //) does not work as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Are you encoding and decoding the URL with URLEncode ? If so, can you check what the input and output of those are ? Seems like one of the **special** characters is not being properly encoded/decoded

Try `%26` for the `&`

Comment: +1 for the '%26' suggestion.  Apparently you shouldn't use URLEncoder to encode URLs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571346/how-to-encode-url-to-avoid-special-characters-in-java.

Answer (score 1):

Try your parameter like

```
summary="Acme &amp; co"
```

`&` is part reserved characters. Refer [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396)  section 
2.2. Reserved Characters.

[how to encode URL to avoid special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571346/how-to-encode-url-to-avoid-special-characters-in-java)

[Characters allowed in GET parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter)

[HTTP URL - allowed characters in parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814700/http-url-allowed-characters-in-parameter-names)

http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.in/2009/12/java-safe-character-handling-and-url.html