# get data from url

Tags: javascript, url, get

i took a ready script from here, [How to read GET data from a URL using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814613/how-to-read-data-from-url-using-javascript) and can't make it work, what im doing wrong?
here is my script:

```
function getUrlParam(param)
{
  param = param.replace(/([\[\](){}*?+^$.\\|])/g, "\\$1");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + param + "=([^&#]*)");
  var url   = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
  var match = regex.exec(url);
  return match ? match[1] : "";
}
var param = getUrlParam("process_number");
alert(param);
```

and here is my link:

```
http://erp.micae.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects.popup_print_files&process_number=SER-498&action_type=141&action_id=289&action_row_id=32&print_type=192
```

thx for the help!

Sorry guys, forgot to mantion that my page is working in a frame, that why it can't get the data from url i want :)

Comment: her eis the improved version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery/5158301#5158301

Comment: That code works perfectly. What is the problem?

Comment: You forgot to tell us **what is the expected result** and **what is the actual result**. *can't make it work, what im doing wrong* is not an error description. Do you expect us to *guess*?

Comment: @Felix Kling i need to take data after "process_number" in this case SER-498 and show it in an opened page, that's all i want

Comment: Sorry guys, forgot to mantion that my page is working in a frame, that why it can't get the data from url i want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're in a frame, if you need to get the href from the main window, do this:

```
var href = window.top.location.href;
```

Then process it.

Answer (score 0):

That code has to run from the page whose URL you're mining for parameter values. In other words, it operates only on the **current** URL of the page it's on.  It works fine.

If you want a function that gives you parameter values given an arbitrary URL, you'd just need to add an additional parameter:

```
function getUrlParam(param, url) {
  param = param.replace(/([\[\](){}*?+^$.\\|])/g, "\\$1");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + param + "=([^&#]*)");
  url   = url || decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
  var match = regex.exec(url);
  return match ? match[1] : "";
}

alert(getUrlParam("process_number", "http://erp.micae.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects.popup_print_files&process_number=SER-498&action_type=141&action_id=289&action_row_id=32&print_type=192"));
```

Comment: thx but, it will work just for one page, the process number and action type and etc are variables that will change...