# Get Url in postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page. On some processing on the page, I am attaching some values to the url with javascript.

```
Ex:
http://localhost:8080/Default.aspx#value1
```

Now I do a postback, How do I get the url with javascript appended values(#value1)?

Comment: Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814613/how-to-read-get-data-from-a-url-using-javascript

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using:

```
request.RawURL
```

Answer (score 2):

try this
`Page.ClientQueryString`

Comment: its not querystring .its like #value1

Answer (score 0):

Request.RawURL will not work either,

The RawUrl property returns the portion of the URL that does not contain the website address.

e.g. In www.example.com/home/account, rawurl will return

> /home/account only.

you need to reserve your url before making a postback.