# enable second page button from first page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to enable or disable the buttons from `page2.php` from `page1.php`. when i click on the submit button from `page1.php` it should `ENABLE/DISABLE` button in the `page2.php` without redirecting to `page2.php`.

here am trying to send value from `page1.php` to `page2.php` using javascript. but unable to get data.

here is what i have tried.

page1.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function enable(){

var enable="enable";
window.location = "page2.php?temp=" + enable;
alert(enable);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

click button to ebable or disable

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="enable"onclick="enable();"> 

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my `page2.php`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function enable(){

var temp=Request.querystring["temp"];

alert(temp);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

click button to ebable or disable
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="enable" onclick="enable()"  > 

</body>
</html>
```

can anyone suggest how to get it.?

Comment: In page 2 where you have taken data from url? and  I think... you have to call enable function on page load.

Comment: Request.quesrystring["temp"] will fetch data from first page. but that's not working.

Comment: Your question is not much clear. Also the code is very confusing. Do you want to disable a button on page1.php and it should show disabled on page2.php when visited? You said the apge should not redirect but you are redirecting it using window.location.

Comment: Reuest.Querystring is not a native function in javascript are you using any library

Comment: sorry for that. let me make it clear. when i click a button on page1.php, it should disable the button on page2.php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814613/how-to-read-get-data-from-a-url-using-javascript have you seen this

Comment: @AjeetKumar this post is very heavy. am unable to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set

```
var x = document.getElementById("button").setAttribute("value", "enable");
```

Like that, you can access that specific variable and edit it's enability.

And using the javascript, you can pass in the value of the button's enability to the second PHP page.

Comment: do i to have to write this in page1.php ?

Comment: can i just ask why you're using javascript instead of using the get or post attribute using the input tag?

Comment: i don't want to redirect to page2.php when i submit data from page1.php. if i use get or post method, it will redirect to page2.php and i don't want that.

Comment: But, to submit, or file a "request", you would need to redirect to page 2

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials of GET and POST method php in google.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93675/discussion-between-muymuy1-and-sagar-pawar).

Answer (score 0):

in page2.php
inside function enable 
after you get temp value

```
if(temp){
    document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**NOTE:** Please Read the comments in the code for more explanation.

**page1.php** and **page2.php** will have JS code like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enable(){
    // Set enable/disable in session to be read on next page and this page on refresh
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "setButtonStatus.php", true);
    xhttp.send();

    // set enable/disable value for current event
    if(this.value == 'enable'){
        this.value = 'disable';   
    } else {
        this.value = 'enable';
    }
}
</script>
```

In **setButtonStatus.php**

```
<?php
// setButtonStatus.php
// Set button status as enable in session if not already set or if disabled
if(isset($_SESSION['setButtonStatus']) && $_SESSION['setButtonStatus'] == 'enable'){
    $_SESSION['setButtonStatus'] = 'disable';
} else {
    $_SESSION['setButtonStatus'] = 'enable';
}
?>
```

**page1.php**  HTML code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['setButtonStatus']) ? $_SESSION['setButtonStatus'] : 'enable' ; ?>" onclick="enable()"  >
```

**page2.php**  HTML code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" disabled="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['setButtonStatus']) && $_SESSION['setButtonStatus'] == 'disabled' ? true : false ; ?>" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['setButtonStatus']) ? $_SESSION['setButtonStatus'] : 'enable' ; ?>" onclick="enable()"  >
```

Comment: thanks it works.. but in page2.php , button still works when it is in disable mode. it should not happen.

Comment: for that you can use `disabled = true` in input field. I have edited the code.

Comment: button is disabled on both sides.

Comment: Yes it should because we are using the same input field in both pages. If you want to disable only from `page2` then remove the disabled attribute from `page1`. let me edit the answer. PS: edited.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below
page1.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function enable(){

var enable="enable";
alert(enable);
window.location = "page2.php?temp=" + enable;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
```

click button to ebable or disable

page2.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#submit{
   display:none;
}
</style>
while page will load button is hide but if in url temp= enable then     buton will be visible
 <input type="button" value="button here" name="submit" id="submit"   <?php if($_GET['temp']=='enable'){ echo "style='display:block'";} ?>> 

 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: this is working, but redirecting to page2.php. I don't want to redirect it. it should pass value only.

Comment: can you please brief what exactly you want to do?

Comment: when I click on button in page1, it should disable button in page2 without redirecting to page2.