# How to get the data from json URL by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Can someone show me how the syntax work to get the data from the JSON of URL by javascript? An example: `JSON` in the `url`

```
({
  "test": 60,
  "homework": 15,
  "quiz": 0,
  "class_participation": 10,
  "final_exam": 15,
  "success": true
})
```

The number represents the weight of the categories, after I get the data out from the URL I want it to automatically fill out all the input box with respectively values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know [how to fetch data from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814613/how-to-read-get-data-from-a-url-using-javascript), and how to store data into URL.

For storing data into URL, you should normalize it that it does not change and does not make you an ugly or unsafe URL.

Let's say your data is in `data` variable which is a JavaScript object.

```
var data = {
  "test": 60,
  "homework": 15,
  "quiz": 0,
  "class_participation": 10,
  "final_exam": 15,
  "success": true
}

var URLData = ncodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

// Pass URLData into URL
```

Now it's time to read, you should use `JSON.parse(your-object)` to read data you read from URL.

Now you need to access items in your JavaScript object.

For the `data` variable, this is how we get items:

```
data.test; // --> 60
data.homework;  // --> 15
data.success  // --> true
```

Comment: I am confusing on how can I fetch data from URL. I tried to look multiples solution but I still lost. Assume, I have URL:http://cs1371.gatech.edu/getClassInfo/?class=CS1371. How can I get the data and store them in the variable? Can you give me some more hint?