# Getting information from URL and showing and hiding html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if a search has been ran so that i can react to this with JS and hide and show different divs depending on that on page load.

How do i get information from the URL with JavaScript and Jquery?

```
www.localhost.com/search?name=&category=
```

I want to get the information of the name and category then if they are not null i want to show this div

```
<div class="Search-results"></div>
```

and hide this one

```
<div class="Search-params"></div>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814613/how-to-read-get-data-from-a-url-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Many of the solutions on this site were done before the newer [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) was implemented and involve parsing strings

Use `URL.searchParams` which has numerous methods for getting, setting and iterating keys and values without having to parse strings

```js
const url =new URL('http://www.localhost.com/search?foo=bar&name=&category=')
const params = url.searchParams;

// check if 2 params exist and have values
if(!params.get('name') && !params.get('category')){
  console.log('name & category are empty or not available')
}
// output value of valid param
console.log('value of foo = ', params.get('foo'))

// add a new param and output updated href string
params.set('new-param', 123);
console.log('Updated url\n', url.href)

// loop through all params
for(let p of params){
   console.log('value of', p[0] , ' is ', p[1] || 'empty')
}
```

Comment: nice man i can see what your doing but i cannot get it to work on my code. Says the searchParams is undefined and just runs the if no matter whether the params are null or not. Any ideas>?

Comment: Are you using full url with protocol? If Is parsing from current page can use `url = URL(location.href)`. Would need to see your code to help

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
if(!searchParams.get('name') && !searchParams.get('category')){

  }
  else{

        $('.search').hide()


}
```