# Can javascript display text of any external file with any extension?

Tags: javascript

Lets consider that I have a text file named **text.txt**. So, now I made a file named **showtext.html** in which I have to write javascript such that it can display the text present in **text.txt**. I assume it would be like :

Text ( text.txt )

```
 Show me up !
```

HTML ( showtext.html )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
   var src = "text.txt";
   document.write( value.get( src ) );
</body>
</html>
```

Output of showtext.html

```
Show me up !
```

In, the above function the **value.get()** gets and then writes the value of the text.txt. So, can javascript really do such ? How can I make the **value.get()** ? Will it support only **.txt** extension or can support any custom extension ? Or this can only be done with PHP ?

Comment: Are you trying to read the file from the *client* or the *server*?

Comment: Yes, this is possible to do in JS and much of the web relies on this capability. The 2 simple approaches are either 1) Serve your text.txt at a URL and make an https request to fetch it from the client, and 2) have a build step that replaces placeholders with the contents of text.txt.

Comment: No, I am not using any server or client, it is present locally !!

Comment: @junvar please add a working example

Comment: Reading files, not so much. JavaScript doesn't have any sense about the server's file system. However, retrieving data is of course possible, e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/814613/589259). So if there is a server component that can handle the request, then you're all set.

Comment: To achieve the same as in your pseudo code, simply load the txt file into the browser. No Javascript is needed and the don't need to write the HTML either.

Comment: If you insists on using a html page, then you can request the file by an ajax call to the url `file:///path/to/the/file`. But this works only, if you load the HTML from a local file too (except you use CORS,; but I do not know if this is possible for local files). It is also possible to redirect the HTML or with java script `document.location = "file:////path..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Local" means "all client, no server" :) If you don't have a server, you can't use things like fetch() (as far as I know, security restrictions prevent that). But you can read a file from the local computer on the client as long as the user selects the file themselves. You can't just read any arbitrary file from the client's computer (again, for security reasons).

If you're okay with letting the user select the file, look into the FileReader API.

HTML:

`<input type='file' id='fileSelector' />`

JS:

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileSelector');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', event => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', readEvent => {
    // In here, readEvent.target.result will have the text of the file for you to work with.
  });
  reader.readAsText(file);
});
```